# FakeItEasy - cannot fake ApplyAppPathModifier from HttpResponse

Tags: mocking, moq, fakeiteasy

In my project we want to mock UrlHelper to test controller's actions. I found code that allows me to do it, unfortunately it's written in Moq: [link](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.com/2013/02/unit-testing-mvc-controllers-mocking.html)

There is a line, which i don't know hot to replace in FIE:

```
response.Setup(s => s.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(s => s);
```

This throws System.NotImplementedException:

```
A.CallTo(() => response.ApplyAppPathModifier(A<string>.Ignored)).CallsBaseMethod();
```

This returns empty string from Url.Action:

```
A.CallTo(() => response.ApplyAppPathModifier(A<string>.Ignored)).Returns("");
```

When I remove that line from code, Url.Action also returns empty string.

I don't want to use 2 different mock libraries, but I don't see any possibility to replace it. MvcMockHelpers which uses Moq works without problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-return-values/#return-values-calculated-at-call-time), `ReturnsLazily` will do the equivalent:

```
A.CallTo(() => response.ApplyAppPathModifier(A<string>.Ignored))
 .ReturnsLazily((string s) => s);
```